# Core Audio and the Phantom Device ID

Tags: macos, cocoa, audio, core-audio, macos-carbon

So here's what is going on.

I am attempting to work with Core Audio, specifically input devices. I want to mute, change volume, etc, etc. I've encountered something absolutely bizarre that I cannot figure out. Thus far, google has been of no help.

When I query the system and ask for a list of all audio devices, I am returned an array of device IDs. In this case, 261, 259, 263, 257.

Using kAudioDevicePropertyDeviceName, I get the following:

261: Built-in Microphone
259: Built-in Input
263: Built-in Output
257: iPhoneSimulatorAudioDevice

This is all well and good.

```
// This method returns an NSArray of all the audio devices on the system, both input and
// On my system, it returns 261, 259, 263, 257
- (NSArray*)getAudioDevices
{
  AudioObjectPropertyAddress propertyAddress = { 
    kAudioHardwarePropertyDevices, 
    kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal, 
    kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster 
  };

  UInt32 dataSize = 0;
  OSStatus status = AudioObjectGetPropertyDataSize(kAudioObjectSystemObject, &propertyAddress, 0, NULL, &dataSize);
  if(kAudioHardwareNoError != status)
  {
    MZLog(@"Unable to get number of audio devices. Error: %d",status);
    return NULL;
  }

  UInt32 deviceCount = dataSize / sizeof(AudioDeviceID);

  AudioDeviceID *audioDevices = malloc(dataSize);

  status = AudioObjectGetPropertyData(kAudioObjectSystemObject, &propertyAddress, 0, NULL, &dataSize, audioDevices);
  if(kAudioHardwareNoError != status) 
  {
    MZLog(@"AudioObjectGetPropertyData failed when getting device IDs. Error: %d",status);
    free(audioDevices), audioDevices = NULL;
    return NULL;
  }

  NSMutableArray* devices = [NSMutableArray array];

  for(UInt32 i = 0; i < deviceCount; i++)
  {    
    MZLog(@"device found: %d",audioDevices[i]);   
    [devices addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:audioDevices[i]]];
  }

  free(audioDevices);

  return [NSArray arrayWithArray:devices];
}
```

The problem crops up when I then query the system and ask it for the ID of the default input device. This method returns an ID of 269, which is **not** listed in the array of all devices.

If I attempt to use kAudioDevicePropertyDeviceName to get the name of the device, I am returned an empty string. Although it doesn't appear to have a name, if I mute this device ID, my built-in microphone will mute. Conversely, if I mute the 261 ID, which is named "Built-In Microphone", my microphone does **not** mute.

```
// Gets the current default audio input device
// On my system, it returns 269, which is NOT LISTED in the array of ALL audio devices
- (AudioDeviceID)defaultInputDevice
{
  AudioDeviceID defaultAudioDevice;
  UInt32 propertySize = 0;
  OSStatus status = noErr;
  AudioObjectPropertyAddress propertyAOPA;

  propertyAOPA.mElement = kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster;
  propertyAOPA.mScope = kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal;
  propertyAOPA.mSelector = kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultInputDevice;
  propertySize = sizeof(AudioDeviceID);

  status = AudioHardwareServiceGetPropertyData(kAudioObjectSystemObject, &propertyAOPA, 0, NULL, &propertySize, &defaultAudioDevice); 

  if(status) 
  { //Error
    NSLog(@"Error %d retreiving default input device",status);
    return 0;
  }

  return defaultAudioDevice;
}
```

To further confuse things, if I manually switch my input to "Line In" and re-run the program, I get an ID of 259 when querying for the default input device, which **is** listed in the array of all devices.

So, to summarize:

I am attempting to interact with the input devices in my system. If I try to interact with device ID 261 which is my "Built-In Microphone", nothing happens. If I try to interact with device ID 269 which is, apparently, a phantom ID, my built-in microphone is affected. The 269 ID is returned when I query the system for the default input device, but it is not listed when I query the system for a list of all devices.

Does anyone know what is happening? Am I simply going insane?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed it.

First off, the phantom device ID was simply a virtual device the system was using.

Secondly, the reason I couldn't mute or do anything with the actual devices was because I was using AudioHardwareServiceSetPropertyData instead of AudioObjectSetPropertyData.

It all works now.